# Syntax error when running python manage.py - django

Tags: python, django

I recently upgraded to python 3 and now when I try to run any django command I get the following error:

```
(env)Matts-MacBook-Air:mysite matt$ python manage.py shell
  File "manage.py", line 12
    $ python manage.py makemigrations polls
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There is no line 12 in manage.py so I don't know what it's complaining about. Has anyone run into this problem before?

Here is the manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: are you sure that your `manage.py` is intact?

Comment: So that's your whole manage.py file? Does it have some invisible character or something? Because it's strange it has only 10 lines but error is on line 12

Comment: That dollar sign looks suspicious: Are you sure your `manage.py` doesn't have a stray line resembling the shell command `$ python manage.py makemigrations polls` at the end of it?

Comment: @xnx I'm new to all of this, but fairly positive. I looked at it in another editor to check.

Comment: @xnx I reopened the file. Deleted the last ) from the end of sys.argv and re-added it. It is now working. Not sure what just happened, but I'm okay with it.

Comment: Random glitch, then. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the isses was, but deleting the last character (the `)` ) and adding it again fixed it.

Comment: doesnot make sense. you mustnot have saved then before posting your question here, if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add your app name after you tell it to makemigrations.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#workflow

Comment: To start a migration for the first time it is needed. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#activating-models